# iTunes notify to server for each payment

Tags: ios, swift, itunes

I am working on subscription type of IOS app and for each payment is there any option to set URL, so my server get notification for each payment done  by user in iTunes.

What's the best way to notify server for subscription auto renew payment in iTunes?

Thanks,
Jigar Joshi

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to get a direct notification from iTunes to your server.

What you can do is have the app receive the notifications of the new payments (though only when it's running) in your `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`.

Then, when you receive a notification of a payment, you can send the info to your server, which should in turn validate the receipt with Apple.